# Ubuntu 19.10 Live CD booting to GRUB 2.04 command line

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, uefi

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 19.10 from a USB stick on my laptop (using UEFI) but I can't because every time I try to boot to the Live CD it doesn't show the GRUB boot menu with:

```
Install Ubuntu
Try Ubuntu without installing
```

Instead, it boots to what you would see if you clicked 'c' in the GRUB menu.

Before it goes to the command line, it shows:

```
Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions.
```

etc...

I need help with this because I want to install Ubuntu on the laptop.
I feel like this might have been an issue with a previous Android X86 install when the GRUB bootloader didn't install correctly but I did format the drive so I'm not sure that is the problem.

So anyway if anyone could help me with this is would appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the 19.10 on your USB stick in the form of an ISO file? Grub 2.04 will not boot ISO files in UEFI mode. Try using Rufus or balenaEtcher to make the installer, if working in Windows or mkusb or Etcher if working in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

When GRUB fails to read the necessary files from our device, it goes in its shell.

So... this means the BIOS was not able to read some sectors and reported the error. It could be that the UEFI feature on that computer is not 100% compatible or that your thumb drive has an actual issue. (or, but probably less likely, the installation on the USB didn't go right)

To test whether the thumb drive is good, reading all the files would be the way to go and make sure that you don't get any error reading them. In Linux it would be something like this:

```
#/bin/bash -e
for f in `find /path/to/usb -type f`
do
    cat $f >/dev/null
done
```

If that script fails, then you have a problem on the thumb drive. I ran in a similar problem when one of my drives wouldn't boot because the file system used RAID-1 in LVM and somehow that doesn't work right in some cases. Fixing the type of file system worked in my case. In your case, you'll have to find out why it's not able to read the data off the drive. Maybe a driver is missing on the USB stick.

Comment: I thought that it may have been the bad sectors so I used DD image mode in Rufus to make the drive bootable and it worked, thanks for the help!